# Stationery in Google Apps/Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

What's the easiest way of having Outlook-esque stationery in Google Apps? We'd like our company branding and various bits and pieces to be shown at the base of every email, but Gmail seems to lack the ability for much other than very simple formatting.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The signature block would appear to be the logical place.

I would caution you against over-stylizing your e-mail. Not everyone is on broadband. Not everyone appreciates images and a lot of formatting in their e-mail. Not everyone is sighted.